# ghost css padding/margin issue?

Tags: css, margin, padding

[CIVITASINC - ATLANTIC AVENUE](http://civitasinc.com/2013/projects/completed/atlantic-avenue/) (view in mobile browser)

So... when you load the page above on your iphone or android, it loads a slideshow using Portfolio Slideshow Pro, a Wordpress plugin.

After you click through to the next slide, there is a 'jump' up at the bottom - I can't figure out if it's padding or margin, but something is either being added or removed, I can't figure it out!

Something in the CSS I am missing? i had tried looking at the code using iOS Simulator and Safari's inspector but am stuck.

any ideas?

Comment: Think you might need to work on your load times. This is still loading for me after a minute or so

Comment: you're right, a plugin called Ubergrid was causing it --- i think i've remedied the page load, thx! now, about that css...

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is that your pager div is being loaded on the mobile view, which is what is causing your margin/padding issue. How are you controlling mobile view? It should be done in a responsive format or at least using media queries. You just need to remove the pager div on mobile views, thats the only thing i can think of